# can a TFS build task check out a specific commit from a repo instead of checking out complete repo

Tags: tfs, build, release

In our organization we have a requirement to have TFS build task should pull from a specific commit, given a stable commit id build task should check out that particular commit from repo, existing TFS repo build task only checks out latest from given branch, can you please advise if this problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no option to do it out-of-the-box in  TFS on-premise build pipeline.

You could choose to not sync sources, then the build will not download the repository, and in the beginning of the build add a Command Line task to **download only the commit** yo want.

About how to disable the get source step in vNext, please refer my reply in this link: [Is it able to ignore/disable the first step Get source in vNext Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421482/is-it-able-to-ignore-disable-the-first-step-get-source-in-vnext-build/46422981#46422981)

For which kind of git command should use, just the same as in Visual Studio: [How do you get a specific version from Git in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599554/how-do-you-get-a-specific-version-from-git-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick for confirming this, and thanks for the links provided here, this solves my problem