# tfs git, retrieving old ssis version from tfs git

Tags: git, tfs

We had an unusual circumstance and we may need to get some prior versions of ssis packages back from tfs git.   Is there a way to do that?   With microsoft only tfs I would see old versions.   With VS 2017 Enterprise and a fairly current TFS GIT all we get is a file manager to view the branch and make changes.  I was thinking, with branches, there might not be a way to access versions that were created outside that branch.   But in this case the version of the package when the branch was created would be adequate.   Is there a way to retrieve old versions of SSIS packages with TFS GIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the old version in the commit history from the `View History` in the `Actions menu` on Visual studio.

[image]

Then select a commit history and right click, select `New Branch` to retrieve the old version into a new branch.

[image]

You can also use git commands to roll back to an old commit.

run `git hist` to list the commits history. And select the commit you want to retrieve.

run `git checkout -b new-branch-name <commit-hash>` to checkout the old version into a new branch.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599554/how-do-you-get-a-specific-version-from-git-in-visual-studio-2015/42398444#42398444) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it works for our visual studio/tfs versions.