# Checkout a commit without updating HEAD

Tags: git

I need to update working directory and index to the state of some commit.
When I run `git checkout` Git updates `HEAD`, `index` and a `working directory`.
I know I can checkout a single file from a commit without updating `HEAD` by simply specifying a path to the file. But what is the best way to do that for the entire working directory?

At the moment I'm simply doing:

```
ID=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
git reset --hard COMMIT_ID
git reset --soft $ID
```

Comment: `git reset --hard` already resets the working directory to an earlier commit.  What about hard reset is _not_ already working for you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes, but it also updates the HEAD. I don't want to change a branch reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `git checkout` with a `dot` as a path

```
git checkout COMMIT_ID .
```

From the man page of [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203):

> `git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…​`
>
> Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents in the index or in the <tree-ish> (most often a commit). When a <tree-ish> is given, the paths that match the  are updated both in the index and in the working tree.
>
> The index may contain unmerged entries because of a previous failed merge. By default, if you try to check out such an entry from the index, the checkout operation will fail and nothing will be checked out. Using -f will ignore these unmerged entries. The contents from a specific side of the merge can be checked out of the index by using --ours or --theirs. With -m, changes made to the working tree file can be discarded to re-create the original conflicted merge result.

Comment: It's more an operating specific feature, `.` means the current directory, and git uses it to calculate that since you have a command line open in the root of the git repository, git knows that you want to checkout all files from the specified "tree-ish"