# Change files in working directory while not changing branch

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

In order to create a clean commit history and get rid of some files I don't want for a PR, I would like to set my working directory to be at the state of my branch, say `B`, but make git remain on branch `A` which is identical with `main`, so I can now stage whatever I want to be part of the commit.

In other words: I want to be on `main`, but have the working directory be like the working directory of another branch `A`.

I know I can `git rebase` and edit, but that involves a lot of steps. I simply want to change the files in the working directory and nothing else.

I've found a hacky way but is there something simpler than:

```bash
git branch -c A B
git reset --soft main
git restore --staged .
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure both your question and your answer have some typos in it. (What is `git branch -b` and `git create -b` ?) And, it sounds like you'd benefit from [reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3528245/184546), and in particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675191/184546) where Regret Type 2 is exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Woops, yes, I must have meant `git branch -c` all the time. Thanks for the amazing answer with regret types: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675191/7483211

Answer (score 0):

Using `git checkout COMMIT .` instead of `git reseset` appears to be slightly more intuitive to me:

```bash
git branch -c A main
git checkout B .
git restore --staged .
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49572040/7483211)

But using `git reset --mixed` is actually the most succinct I think:

```bash
git branch -c A B
git reset --mixed main
```

as `--soft` puts changes in staging, while `--mixed` makes changes unstaged.